# Shell navigation to page with tabs + back button

Tags: .net, maui

Using Shell, I am trying to navigate from my `Overview` page (`ContentPage`), to my `Details` page (`TabBar`), but I need the back button.

`AppShell.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="NavigationTests.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavigationTests"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Overview"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Overview}"
        Route="Overview" />

    <TabBar Route="Details">

        <Tab Title="Inner Page 1">
            <ShellContent Title="Inner Page 1"
                          Route="InnerPage1">
                <ContentPage>
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label 
                            Text="Inner Page 1"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Inner Page 2">
            <ShellContent Title="Inner Page 2"
                          Route="InnerPage2">
                <ContentPage>
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label 
                            Text="Inner Page 2"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>

    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

`AppShell.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class AppShell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TestPage), typeof(TestPage));
    }
}
```

`Overview.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NavigationTests.Overview">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Button
                Text="Details"
                Clicked="OnDetailsClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                Text="Test Page"
                Clicked="OnTestPageClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

`Overview.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class Overview
{
    public Overview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnDetailsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//InnerPage1");
    }

    private void OnTestPageClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/TestPage");
    }
}
```

[image: Overview]
[image: TestPage with back button]
[image: tabs without back buttons]

The documentation says `When a route from the Shell visual hierarchy is navigated to, a navigation stack isn't created. However, when a page that's not in the Shell visual hierarchy is navigated to, a navigation stack is created.`

So I have created a `TestPage` to illustrate just that, it's not declared in the `AppShell` visual hierarchy (`AppShell.xaml`) and I just declare its route in the code behind, and that works fine. When I navigate to my `TestPage` I have a back button.

How can I declare my tabs without having them in the visual hierarchy?

I am open to suggestions without Shell...

Comment: The reason the tab is not pushed to nav stack (which would add the back button), is because a tabbar paradigm isn't like browsing pages; tabbar implies user does the tabs in any order. There isn't anything "special" about the tab that is shown first. Don't use tabbar; **don't define tabs in shell (Except the Overview page)**. INSTEAD: **On the home page, add a horizontal or vertical stacklayout of Buttons,** and have each button's click action navigate to the desired page. Then, as you see with TestPage, you'll get back arrow.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to navigate from my Overview page (ContentPage), to my
> Details page (TabBar), but I need the back button.

This can be implemented by creating your own Shell Navigation stack and override `OnBackButtonPressed()` and `OnNavigated` to achieve this feature.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    private Stack<ShellNavigationState> Uri { get; set; } // Navigation stack.  
    private ShellNavigationState temp; // Prevents applications from adding redundant data to the stack when the back button is clicked. 
    public AppShell()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
        Uri = new Stack<ShellNavigationState>();
            
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TestPage), typeof(TestPage));
    }

    protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigated(args);
        if (Uri != null && args.Previous != null)
        {
            if (temp == null || temp != args.Previous)
            {
                Uri.Push(args.Previous);
                temp = args.Current;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (Uri.Count > 0)
        {
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync(Uri.Pop());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this possible solution from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1153025/maui-shell-app-back-button but did not manage to make it work. I'll give it another go on a clean solution.

Comment: @Seb Thanks for the update, I've tested it and it works.

Comment: I can't get it to work. How do you navigate to the other page? Via `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()`? The `TestPage` for which you register the route in the constructor, is that the page with the tabs? Is it a TabbedPage?

Comment: @Seb When starting the app, clicking the details button, it'll navigate to the `Details` page with tab bar. Then you can click the system back button which is at the bottom of the screen to go back to the starting page.

Comment: I see, 1) I can only navigate to details with `//Details` or `///Details`. `Details` alone or `/Details` don't work. and 2) it doesn't create a back button in the navigation bar, that's what I really need :)

Comment: You need to use `//route`  or `route` as the route hierarchy will be searched for the specified route, upwards from the current position. The matching page will replace the navigation stack. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#relative-routes

Comment: Indeed that’s what I have seen there and there, but it doesn’t work, maybe it’s a bug?

Comment: @Seb What do you mean it doesn't work? Is there any error log?

Comment: here's a little repo that illustrates what I mean, the red buttons don't work, the green ones do, however, I only get a back button with `TestPageOutsideVisualHierarchy` and `/TestPageOutsideVisualHierarchy`.

Comment: https://github.com/sebdesalvador/ShellWithBackButton

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the sample and get back to you!